# How to conver dictionary[String:String] to URLQueryItem in swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5

> I have one parameter dictionary

```
  func queryItems(dictionary: [String:Any]) -> URLQueryItem {
    var components = URLComponents()
    print(components.url!)
    components.queryItems = dictionary.map {
        URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: ($1 as! URLQueryItem))
    }
   return (components.url?.absoluteString)!
}
```

I created one function but its not working

Comment: You say it's a `[String: String]` dictionary, but you have declared `[String: Any]`. If you declare it as `[String: String]`  and remove `as! URLQueryItem` that makes no sense, it will work. Of course, the return value will be a `String`, not `URLQueryItem`.

Comment: then I am getting this error

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected element type 'Array<URLQueryItem>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'URLQueryItem')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code makes no sense for several reasons:

1. The return value is `URLQueryItem` but you return a `String`
2. You create an empty `URLComponents` instance which is pointless without scheme, host and path.
3. The `value` of an `URLQueryItem` cannot be `URLQueryItem`

What you can do is just map the dictionary to an array of `URLQueryItem`

```
func queryItems(dictionary: [String:String]) -> [URLQueryItem] {
    return dictionary.map(URLQueryItem.init)
}
```

Alternatively add a second parameter and pass the URL

```
func queryItems(for url: URL, dictionary: [String:String]) -> URL? {
    guard var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else { return nil }
    components.queryItems = dictionary.map(URLQueryItem.init)
    return components.url
}
```

Comment: `dictionary.map(URLQueryItem.init)`?

Comment: I don't know what happened to the first half of my comment which was "Why not simply ...?". Swift is a type inferred language. If you are mapping any collection which its elements is a tuple in the case of this dictionary Element is a KeyValue pair `(key: String, value: String)`). You can pass any type initializer to the map method that consists in two string parameters.

Comment: As you can see I already updated my answer

Comment: I have already seen it. Much better now. I am just expanding the comment for future readers.